# Java thread not sleeping

Tags: java, multithreading

I have this code(FULL SOURCE CODE) :-

```
class thread implements Runnable {
    int i=0;
    Thread t;
    public void main(){
     t= new Thread(this); //edited
        for(i=0;i<=5;i++){
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }

    public void run(){
        try{
            Thread.sleep(1000); //EDITED EARLIER, was: t.sleep(1000); 
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e){
        }
    }
}
```

The thread is supposed to sleep for 1 second. But, the thread does not sleep at all. Where am I going wrong. Any help will be appreciated.

**EDIT**
I get the following error now ->

```
java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException
at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:682)
at thread.main(thread.java:7)
```

Comment: You didn't start the thread...Also, `sleep` is a `static` method.

Comment: Who calls your "main" method, this is not the public static void main

Comment: I am doing this program in blueJ and I am running the main method @RamonBoza

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis when I used `t.start();` in the loop, I get the following error -> `java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException
 at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:682)
 at thread.main(thread.java:7)` When run

Comment: you can start thread just once.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The fundamental issue here is that you never start the thread. Your program's `main` is called on the default thread, you *create* an instance, and then do nothing with it.

If you want to start your thread, call `t.start()` (once). That will start your thread, which will run alongside the default thread the JVM created when running your program. Other than that both threads are running at the same time, they don't interact in your program, so you'll still see the numbers get printed out right away. Depending on what you're trying to do, you may want to move your loop from `main` to `run`.

(And yes, `sleep` is a static method which makes the *current* thread sleep. In Java, it's syntactically valid to call a static method through an instance reference, but it's a bad idea.)

So for instance, here's your class with minimal mods (**note**: your environment seems to create an instance and call the instance-specific `main` below, which is non-standard,but I left it alone as it seems to be what your environment does):

```
class ThreadExample implements Runnable
{
    public void main(){
        Thread t= new Thread(this);
        t.start();
    }

    public void run(){
        int i;

        try{
            Thread.sleep(1000); 
            for(i=0;i<=5;i++){
                System.out.println(i);
            }
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e){
        }
    }
}
```

Changes:

- Use standard Java naming conventions for the class.
- Make `t` a local variable in `main`.
- Actually start the thread in `main`.
- Move loop from `main` to `run`, after the `sleep` call.
- Make `i` a local variable in `run`.
- Call `sleep` via `Thread` rather than `this`.

Here's a more normal example with a static `main`:

```
class ThreadExample implements Runnable
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadExample());
        t.start();
    }

    public void run(){
        int i;

        try{
            Thread.sleep(1000); 
            for(i=0;i<=5;i++){
                System.out.println(i);
            }
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e){
        }
    }
}
```

[Live example with debug output](http://ideone.com/Iw4p1w)

Comment: Your code does not wait for 1 second either...What I did is in the loop (**IN THE MAIN METHOD**), I put this -> `run();` and it works!

Comment: @BenLind: You never call the `run` method of a thread or `Runnable` directly; it's called *implicitly* when you run the thread. If you call `run` directly, you execute the method **on the current thread**, not on the new one. I don't know what you mean about the code above not waiting a second; it does. Proof: http://ideone.com/Iw4p1w

Comment: you can check with using bigger time values

Comment: When you call run();, you are not running the thread, you are just calling a method. Try adding t.join(); after t.start(); to tell your program to wait for the thread to finish executing before exiting.

Answer (score 1):

The `sleep` method in `Thread` is static, so it should be called `Thread.sleep()` and it actually makes the currently executing thread to sleep, not a specific thread instance that you call the method on.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should look more like this. It has been a while since I've worked with threads so there might be minor errors people should feel free to edit.

```
class myThread implements Runnable
{
    public void main(){
        MyThread t= new MyThread();
        t.start();
        t.join();
    }

    public void run(){
        try{
            for(i=0;i<=5;i++){
                System.out.println(i);
                Thread.sleep(1000); 
            }
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e){
        }
    }
}
```